# Why is my CPU Frequency stuck?

Tags: 14.04, cpufreq

After recent routine upgrades, I've noticed that I'm unable to change my CPU frequency manually. The system is doing it automatically, and choosing the highest frequency possible, which causes it to run hot (it already has heating issues).

Most of the fixes I found are on threads from 2010 or earlier, and are no longer applicable.

Here is the output of `cpufreq-info`:

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.80 GHz and 1.80 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.80 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:77.10%, 1.80 GHz:0.01%, 1.20 GHz:22.86%, 800 MHz:0.02%  (74)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.80 GHz and 1.80 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.80 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:77.09%, 1.80 GHz:0.02%, 1.20 GHz:22.88%, 800 MHz:0.02%  (73)
```

The output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq`:

```
1801000
```

Comment: what is the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq`

Comment: Updated the question. I'm also stumped because that should be 800000

Comment: reads like a kernel bug e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/704567 - think it might be worth playing with installing either an earlier or later kernel from the mainline - e.g. if it was working with 13.10 - install kernel 3.8

Comment: type in terminal "uname -r" and post here your kernel version. Since it is happening only after updates, it is most likely the kernel.

Comment: @foss & rat - you may be right, I think it started after a routine kernel update.

Comment: @RolandiXor- obviously you can test that theory by booting from an early kernel via Grub ... good luck :)

Comment: @fossfreedom I haven't tried it yet, but it will depend on if I still have any old kernels installed lol. I usually remove them shortly after updating.

Comment: Using an older kernel didn't fix it - so I'm assuming the problem lies somewhere else, such as in cpufreq-utils. I was suspecting that might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was `cpufreqd`, which had gotten pulled in when I installed Ubuntu MATE Desktop. Removing it returned control to the system and now I can use my system without it unnecessarily overheating.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this fixed the problem for me on a Thinkpad x220 with Ubuntu 14.04, having the cpu frequency stuck at 800 MHz after hibernate and suspend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the scaling_min_freq is not being set to the lower frequencies, preventing the governor from accessing these freqs.  As an attempt to see if this can be manipulated, enter the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-1]/cpufreq; do echo 800000 > $x/scaling_min_freq; done
exit
```

If this produces the desired result, you can  place the loop in the script into /etc/rc.local. If it does not, then I would reboot the system to get back into a known operable state.  On my system, I also needed to add the line `echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc`, which I execute before the loop.

Comment: Wouldn't running this in a loop cause problems?

Comment: I'm not a bash god, but the loop is controlled by the [0-1] in the for statement. In my computer, it's [0-3], as each of the 4 cores in my computer needs to have a parameter set separately.

Comment: No, the 0-1 tells it to set that for both processor cores. But, your saying to add it as a loop to /etc/rc.local - so what I'm wondering about is if this is supposed to run only on boot or constantly as a loop while the system is on. (I'm assuming the former but just need to be sure).

Comment: No, only runs once.  Goes through the loop for each `x` as described by /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-1]/cpufreq, which in this case is cpu0 and cpu1