# Automatic switching between performance and powersave mode on plugging in/out the power supply

Tags: 14.10, power-management, performance

Recently I've been trying to investigate why my laptop is so slow. I found out that it runs at ~600Mhz, regardless of the power supply being plugged in or not. Note that it's  Intel i5-2540M nominally running at 2.60GHz. So I find it very strange to be clocked at ~600Mhz all the time, even if it's loaded with some computations. This even affect web browsing, so it's quite annoying.

I further investigated this issue and it turns out the clock is related to so called CPU governor mode. On my system it's always set to `powersave`, no matter if the power supply is plugged in or not. I think it should be switched to `performance` mode (or something in between, if possible) when the power supply is plugged in. Note that switching to `performance` mode manually solves the problem - the laptop becomes much more responsive.

Does Ubuntu have any support for such automatic switching of CPU governor modes? Is there any package I should install or a configuration file which I need to edit?

I am aware of the `pm-utils` package which provides some power related notifications so I could use it as the foundation of a simple script which does the CPU governor switching fully automatically. Still I might be unaware of some limitations or gotchas of such an approach. So I want to know if this is the right one.

Thanks in advance!

BTW, my setup is Ubuntu 14.10

```
$ uname -a
Linux aromanek-laptop 3.16.0-34-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 18:02:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x12
cpu MHz     : 633.242
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5188.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

UPDATE:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate
intel_pstate

$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/pstate_snb/d_gain_pct
0
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/pstate_snb/p_gain_pct
20
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/pstate_snb/i_gain_pct
0
```

Comment: Which frequency scaling driver are you using? Do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and edit your question to include the result. You should not, indeed do not want, to run performance mode with the intel-pstate driver, and powersave mode should ramp up the CPU frequency as required (it is basically the same as `ondemand` mode for the acpi-cpufreq driver. The question is why doesn't it?

Comment: If your scaling driver is intel_pstate, then please also add your question the outputs from: `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/pstate_snb/d_gain_pct` and `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/pstate_snb/p_gain_pct` and `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/pstate_snb/i_gain_pct`. (just trying to determine if your processor is Bay Trail or other nick name).

Comment: Your processor seems to be `Sandy Bridge`. It should ramp up the CPU frequency as required by increased load. However, there have been reports of issues after resume from suspend. You could try forcing the acpi-cpufreq driver (I'll make an answer with how in a minute).

Comment: I think I know what was wrong, and why switching to performance mode "kicks" it out of the stuck state. I have proposed a patch to correct the issue.

Comment: Good to know the problem has been identified.

Comment: Is you LapTop a Dell? Regardless, would you be willing to try tests detailed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/624937/my-cpu-slows-down-after-a-while-and-does-not-recover/664333#664333) and report back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try forcing the acpi-cpufreq scaling driver. To do so, edit (as sudo) the `/etc/default/grub` file and change the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" line, adding this (and my example has some other stuff for my case that was there before):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 intel_pstate=disable crashkernel=384M-:128M"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then re-boot.
You should find that your Ubuntu system will default to the `ondemand` governor about 1 minute after boot up.

I would be interested to pursue why you seem to be having issues with the intel-pstate driver.

To answer your actual question, look into the [laptop-mode-tools package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/laptop-mode-tools) and it [configuration](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/laptop-mode.conf.8.html)

Comment: Indeed, disabling the `intel_pstate` driver helped - the CPU clock is now correctly managed as the load increases and decreases. What else could I do to investigate the issue with the `intel_pstate` driver? BTW, I've just started the upgrade procedure to Ubuntu 15.04. We'll see how the `intel_pstate` driver behaves on this distro. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: The intel_pstate driver is unchanged between the currrent 14.10 and 15.04 kernels, regardless it would be interesting to check. Do you know if current misbehavior only starts after any hibernate or suspend event?

Comment: Hi, I had a similar problem with a Thinkpad x220 on Ubuntu 14.04. I found the answer in a different question. I had to remove cpufreqd to let the system regain control of the cpu frequency.

To recreate the error, I think I need to be in a low battery state, let the laptop suspend, wake up. Then my `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` is set to 800000 https://askubuntu.com/questions/517844/why-is-my-cpu-frequency-stuck/524392#524392

Comment: @DougSmythies I think it would be best to specify that the `intel_pstate=disable` parameter is key, and even remove the other ones from your example. Inexperienced users might be unsure which parameters are "other stuff" and add them all.

Answer (score 1):

My laptop doesn't seem to come with an "ondemand" scheduler for reasons that eludes me, but my solution was to switch between powersave and performance based on the state of the AC Mains. I've added a udev rule with the following content:

/etc/udev/rules.d/50-scaling-govoner.rules

```
    SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{type}=="Mains", ATTR{online}=="1", RUN+="/usr/bin/cpufreq-set -g performance -r"
    SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{type}=="Mains", ATTR{online}=="0", RUN+="/usr/bin/cpufreq-set -g powersave -r"
```

Br,
Martin