# Dell Latitude E6420 with Ubuntu 16.10 becomes very slow after closing laptop or suspending manually

Tags: suspend, dell, 16.10, memory-usage, wakeup

PC:
Ubuntu Latitude E6420
Core i7 2.8GHz 8GB ram

Ubuntu 16.10

After I close my laptop or manually suspend session, when wakeup it becomes terribly slow. Reboot solves it, but becomes unpractical. Anyone knows any fix for this? Not sure what it is causing this bug.

EDIT: I upgraded to 17.04. Before upgrading, I noticed that when after wake I get some glitches bellow opened windows and bars. After upgrade, all is the same.

[after waking up - glitches bellow opened windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x49Bp.png)

[desktop look after minimize all opened windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsAp4.jpg)

Comment: This (the slow down part, never heard of the memory part) might be a known issue with mainly Dell, but also some other, LapTops. Does it occur on battery power only or also when on AC power? The known issue was battery only, and is a fundamental incompatibility between the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver and Dell's use of clock modulation upon resume from suspend on battery power.

Comment: Well the memory part was only a guess. The slowness is something that occurs. Not sure yet about battery/AC. I'll try all options, and let you know. Doug, That issue that is know has a fix?

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/709756/low-cpu-frequency/728871#728871), which has another two follow on links. But please please don't just work around the issue and move on. Report back. The reason this issue isn't getting fixed seems to be that the stake holders do not know how serious and wide spread it is.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I have a very important work to finish in my laptop. After that I will try to take a deep look into it, and report back. Don't worry.
I've previously did that mistake of not reporting because I did so many different things to solve an issue, that I couldn't even tell which worked. I'll be more cautious this time!

Comment: So far I can say that if I close the laptop with AC cable on, and open back, it runs well. Later I'll perform your tests, Doug. I'll try all possibilities and report the results.

Comment: Hi, Doug, I was about to start the tests you advised me to (https://askubuntu.com/questions/624937/my-cpu-slows-down-after-a-while-and-does-not-recover/664333#664333).
But I got "sudo: rdmsr: command not found" on step 2.

Btw, I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04. When I manually suspend my laptop, either by hitting suspend option or closing laptop, when I wake I get some glitches bellow my opened windows, and bars.

Comment: There is a note further down in that reference: "Note: rdmsr and wrmsr are contained in the msr-tools package, which I do not recall if it is installed by default or not." (I guess not)

Comment: oh, I must've missed that part. Sorry. I'll get back to you

Comment: I ran the tests. I confirmed that the values only change when suspend without AC adapter on. Without it the values change to 1c. But, the glitch appears always! Doug, have you ever heard of this glitch? (please see photos on EDIT).