# Performance drop under 20% battery life

Tags: power-management, performance, battery, cpu

I own a Dell XPS 9370 laptop with an i7 8550U.

I recently noticed, that my performance decreases quite significantly when my battery percentage drops under 20%. This especially visible on GNOMEs animations, which start to get pretty laggy. This happens in all Ubuntu versions from 18.04 to 19.10 I tested.

I tried to investigate a bit and observed that my CPU frequency does not scale up properly anymore, it does not reach the max frequency of my processor (4 GHz) by far after my battery life falls under 20%. When running with over 20%, it scales properly up to the 4 GHz.

Setting the CPU governor to `performance` removes that impact but is obviously not a solution, as that has a serious impact on the battery life.

So all in all it feels like a power saving feature of the governor. Is there a possibility to turn it off or move the battery percentage that kicks in? Maybe some kernel parameter?
Any additional ideas to solve that problem?

Cheers in advance

P.S: I uninstalled all additional power saving tools I know of (`tlp` etc.), but that did not help either.

Comment: This is not a kernel thing, nor anything to do with any governor. As far as I know, it is a Dell thing. When under 20% battery what do you get for `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`?

Comment: @DougSmythies Good to know. Those are the values for over 20%:
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` returns `100` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` returns `0`.

I will add those for under 20% after my battery life dropped...

Comment: Low battery situations dictate shutting off powerr to subsystems. Then when they are accessed power up introduces more latency. That's my guess.

Comment: Dell forces "clock modulation" via the BIOS under some circumstances, this might be one of them. To determine for certain see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624937/my-cpu-slows-down-after-a-while-and-does-not-recover/664333#664333). And note: you may find around here comments from me saying "the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver is fundamentally incompatible with clock modultion". That is no longer true, but it will limit your max frequency.

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : I missed that you mentioned "for over 20%". Only look into clock modulation if the other numbers stay after battery < 20%.

Comment: Just checked it this morning and yeah, they stay the same under 20%.

Comment: @DougSmythies So, looked into the clock modulation today. But unfortunately, the output of `sudo rdmsr -a 0x19a` stays 0 even if its under 20% and throttled. So that might not be the reason...

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : O.K. so I seem to have wasted your time. The only other thing I can think of is via this path: `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq`. Depending on your kernel version, the two methods may or may not be interlinked.

Comment: @DougSmythies You did not have wasted my time at all! Thanks for your support and the time you invested and I am really sorry if my respond sounded rude :(

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : Not at all, and actually thanks for even replying, as a very very high percentage of posters we never hear back from and are left wondering, as are future readers.

Comment: @DougSmythies Alright. And I had a look into the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq`, which stays 4000000 even if throttled. So it looks like, that might not be the reason either...
By the way, currently running the 5.3 kernel.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix What are the subsystems you think about? Do you have any idea how to check?

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : Hmmm... this one is interesting. While it doesn't make sense, I wonder about idle injection (either old way with kidle_inject, or the new way with idle_inject (only the hooks are supposed to be in place for the new way so far, I think)). One way to check would be via `top` and or via `ps aux`.

Comment: @DougSmythies (and Ghost) I was thinking powering off HDD or SSD which could explain performance drop. Besides being powered off some devices have sleep states. The USB bus is another power drain. You could check `dmesg` as soon as you notice system slowing down. Probably at the same time you should notice the screen getting dimmer?

Comment: @DougSmythies That sounds interesting. Could you be a bit more specific on how test/observe whether that is the case?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I actually do not experience screen dimming, only a performance drop...
For which entries would I like in `dmesg`?

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : I would use `top`, and then observe a lot of CPU time allocated to `kidle_inject` tasks, one task per CPU. You might also see `idle_inject`, but they should still be at 0% CPU, because as far as I know they are only hooks so far for future use. Otherwise, we'll have to move to a chat, as further investigation will be somewhat complicated, requiring some back and forth.

Comment: @DougSmythies Alright, I will have a look into it when my battery is going down again.
And yes, your idea of switching to a messenger sounds great, just tell me which one you prefer :)

Comment: @DougSmythies Battery life dropped and performance throttled again. But `htop` does not return any process when I filter for `idle`...

Furthermore, `dmesg -T` shows the last entry with a timestamp from two hours ago...

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : If you are willing, it is time to try `turbostat`, and to start looking directly at the p-state requested and p-state granted registers. `turbostat` (linux-tools-common package) can spew a bunch of stuff at startup that may or may not help. As a starting point suggest: `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. The pstate requested/granted MSRs are via `sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:8 -d -a 0x199` and `sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:8 -d -a 0x198`. This thiing will automatically ask us to move to chat, eventually.

Comment: @InvisibleShadowGhost : Oh, and by the way, you might find that using the performance governor is not all that expensive in terms of energy. Yes, the CPU frequency ramps up faster, but also the job gets done faster resulting in more time in deep idle states. The cost on my very idle server is 0.8%.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101145/discussion-between-doug-smythies-and-invisibleshadowghost).